# Angular Material Select not showing defaulted selection

Tags: angular-material

Within a form, I can't get a preselected option to show up on a select. 
If you look at material select example without the form elements, it works, but with form, while the model is correct and if I hit "submit" on my form it works, but I'd really like it to display the defaulted answer upon opening the form.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5367rp?file=app%2Fselect-hint-error-example.html

It should look like the example (Select with two-way binding) at: https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples where "Option 2" is clearly preselected.

Comment: If I take off FormControl everything works...but that is not exactly an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using forms, you usually don't bind to the 'value' property because the form control effectively replaces it. So to 'pre-select' a value, you set it on the form control:

```
animals: Animal[] = [
    {name: 'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'},
    {name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'},
    {name: 'Cow', sound: 'Moo!'},
    {name: 'Fox', sound: 'Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!'},
];
// selected = "Dog"; // don't use this
animalControl = new FormControl(this.animals[0], [Validators.required]);
```

Comment: I just wanted to say in case someone comes across this issue, I had originally tried the solution above except I had been trying to use my ENUM, for example: animalControl = new FormControl(Animals.CAT, [Validators.required]); and it was NOT working, so I assumed it could not be done that way...Now I am using a string. Not actually using an array, but I did test that out in the stackblitz and it was working fine, just not working on my actual form. I am happy regardless and THanks again.

Comment: Instances of native types like strings or numbers are interchangeable, so if `a = 'this_string'` and `b = 'this_string'` then `a === b`. But with other things like objects and I assume enums, if `a = { value: 'this_string' }` and `b = { value: 'this_string' }`, `a === b` fails because they are different objects. That's why in my example I used `FormControl(this.animals[0], [Validators.required])` - referencing the same object, and not `FormControl({name: 'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'}, [Validators.required])` which specifies an identical but different object. The latter use would not have worked.